# Align dropdown menu container

Tags: custom-fields

**Hello,**

**I've been trying to align and set the width of the dropdown menu container so that it showed perfectly aligned with the field label in terms of position and width in all screen sizes.**

**Any Ideas ?**

[image: Text]

Comment: Hey Ibrahim, can you post the solution you have tried here? This way it is easier for others to help you out.

Comment: @em_code I've tried to use position: relative and margin: 0 auto